# Is it possible to recover the key to a decrypted file?

Tags: decompilation, decryption, encryption, cryptography, decompiler

Is it possible to recover the key to a decrypted file if you have the initialization vector and it uses RijndaelManaged? If so how?

The file I want to recover the key from is a xml that looks like this without encryption. It has a xml element called Test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test />
```

When it is encrypted with the key *`stackoverflow`* (73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc = md5 hash) and the initialization vector below, the file look like this *`¥4!¬Hw[î!71ôtž|!¢¬TÞ;u?þª-†•ÈÏ‰eßŽKtSsbZ®ÕµR©Ù«í‹`*:

[image: File looks like this]

Initialization vector:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[]
{
    55, 66, 77, 192, 57, 100, 11, 111,
    25, 86, 96, 66, 22, 122, 133, 43
};
```

Is it possible to reverse the key from that or are it bulletproof?

Comment: it uses CBC mode and padding value PKCS7 is that going to make a differents? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in a cryptography Stack Exchange, not the Reverse Engineering one.

Answer (score 2):

From my limited cryptographical knowledge and a quick Google search to confirm it, no.

This would be a known-plaintext attack and AES is engineered to be resistant to it.